# execute xcodebuild test with '-enableCodeCoverage=YES' option but the result Coverage.profdata looks invalid

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

Recently I'm preparing UITesting for our app.

My XCode version is 7.3.1(7D1014). 
When I had executed 'UITesting' in XCode as manual, I got the coverage report successfully as below.

[UITesting executed by xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDv9d.png)

But I execute test that project with command line, created "Coverage.profdata" file size is different with xcode. And change that coverage data to 'cobertura' using 'slather', the result is zero.

Here is my xcodebuild statement.

> xcodebuild test -project SampleTestApp.xcodeproj -scheme SampleTestApp -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,OS=9.3' -enableCodeCoverage YES

I think, I missed something. Is there anyone who experienced like me?
I need your help.

I looked log file furthermore. And I found something different between XCode testing and xcodebuild testing.

A. XCode Testing Log(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectXXX/Logs/Test/XXXXX/Session-XXXXXX.log)

- "wait_for_debugger" set 1 in Tests-Runner options

B. xcodebuild Testing Log(~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectXXX/Logs/Test/YYYYY/Session-YYYYY.log)

- "wait_for_debugger" set 0 in Tests-Runner options

I wonder i can change this option value when executes test-runner.

Comment: I think this issue https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov/issues/22 similar situation

Comment: Another difference that I found interesting is: `Launching with Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn` when tests are run with xcodebuild and `Launching with Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB` when running from Xcode. Xcode scheme contains `selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Debugger.LLDB"
selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.Launcher.LLDB"` It seems like xcodebuild ignores these settings.

Comment: If you disable `Debugger [] Debug Executable` settings in Xcode scheme, the settings become `selectedDebuggerIdentifier = "" selectedLauncherIdentifier = "Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn"`

Comment: So, when tests are run using `xcodebuild` they behave as `Debugger [] Debug Executable` would be unchecked.

Comment: When run using `xcodebuild` `"wait_for_debugger" = 0` and `Launching with Xcode.IDEFoundation.Launcher.PosixSpawn` happens for both Unit Tests and UI Tests. For unit tests coverage data is valid, though.

Comment: One more difference between Unit Tests and UI Tests is: running Unit Tests in Xcode with `Debug Executable` disabled gives valid coverage results while running UI Tests with `Debug Executable` disabled gives 0%. I suppose the way UI Tests and Unit Tests are run behind the scene makes the difference. https://s32.postimg.org/msd8951jp/Screen_Shot_2016_07_12_at_1_42_24_PM.png